# When is CSS transition loaded and triggered?

Tags: css

Below is a CSS code snippet to transit a button from #33ae74 to #1ce when hover it.

```
.button {
  font-size: 3em;
  font-family: inherit;
  border: none; 
  background-color: #33ae74;
  padding: 0.5em 0.75em;
}

.button:hover {
  background-color: #1ce;
  transition: background-color 2s ease-out;
}
```

It works well. My question is: before mouse hover,there is no transition bind to the button,why transition works when hover it? In another case, when hover, transition bind to the button, meanwhile the background color also be changed to #1ce immediately,so there should no color be transited. but why we could still see the transition?

Comment: Because you have added `transition` property on the `.button:hover `.

Comment: See this: https://codepen.io/manaskhandelwal1/pen/abpmmWo

Answer (score 0):

that's very simple just make the transition on the original element. By doing that the transition will work when you hover and will work when the over is done.

```css
.button {
  font-size: 3em;
  font-family: inherit;
  border: none;
  background-color: #33ae74;
  padding: 0.5em 0.75em;
  transition: background-color 2s ease-out;
}

.button:hover {
  background-color: #1ce;
}
```

```html
<button class="button">hover over me</button>
```